# Async Webmethod timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am making an asynchronous call to an `.asmx` web service and I am constantly getting a timeout. It doesn't matter what time is set the timeout on the binding in the client it is always exceeded.

```
<binding 
     name="xxxxxxxxx" closeTimeout="00:20:00" openTimeout="00:20:00" 
     receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00"/>
```

The web method invokes two stored procedures which have no parameters. I have run them manually and they both run successfully, taking 31 seconds and 6 minutes.

Taking this into account I would expect a time-out of 10 minutes to be more than enough and have even tried 20 minutes but they both time-out.

I have set the `executionTimeout` property of httpRuntime to 600 in the `web.config` and made sure `debug=false`, but I am still getting this error.

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="600"/>
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5">
```

Can anybody help?

UPDATE:

I am calling from a winforms application.

If I run the web service manually from the browser I get a timeout as well:

[image]

UPDATE 2:

Upped the `executionTimeout` to 800 and I can now run the web service successfully via the browser, but still getting the error when I call it from the desktop application.

UPDATE 3:

I added an old style, non-WCF based web reference and I still get the timeout.

Comment: Need more information in order to be able to help. How are you calling the ASMX? From a console app? WinForms? Cellphone? Where are you seeing a timeout? In the caller? In the ASMX? What does the error state? Have you tried invoking the ASMX itself directly from a browser / `curl` / etc.

Comment: ASMX is **not** WCF - yet the config you're showing with the `<binding>` seems to point to WCF - so what are you really using?? ASMX or WCF? Please tag correctly - only the technology actually in use here...

Comment: The server is an .asmx file. The client is uses a webreference that is a WCF based client. So it has both technologies.